# dropdown nav menu not working properly with ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

[image][image: Here is the snapshot]i am working on dropdown nav menu. some how it is not working properly with IE 8 and lesser versions. I am thinking it might be the issue with percentage width on IE.

here is my HTML

```css
![here is the snapshot][3]
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar {
    list-style:none;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
}
.navbar li li {
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
.navbar li {
    width:20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font: normal bold 12px/1em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
    color:White;
    background-color: #660099;
}
.navbar a {
    padding:9px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-right: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #660099;
    display: block;
}
.navbar li:hover, .navbar li.hover, .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar li:hover ul, .navbar li.hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar li ul li a {
    border-left: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-right: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-top: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #660099;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <ul style="width:100%" class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#parent1">parent1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#parent2">parent2</a>

            <ul class="childNav">
                <li><a href="#child1">child1sdfsfgggggggggggffdgdssdfgffgd</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#child2">child2sdfgfsdgfdsgfghgjgjkgghjg</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#parent3">parent3</a>

            <ul class="childNav">
                <li><a href="#Support">child1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#Support">child2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Support">contactus</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: How improperly is it working? Does anything appear at all?

Comment: yeah like last parent item( for example : contact us from code) is showing in next line.

Comment: I have added the snapshot please check it @JacqueGoupil

Comment: @sdcr: no i dont have a live site. can you test it in IE 7 , you can able to see the difference

Comment: @sdcr: hmm thats weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a reset.css file to remove browser-specific defaults. Make one that suits your needs. [This one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a good start.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

I personally always do this too:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

JSfiddle has a built-in reset CSS option. I tried [your page there](http://jsfiddle.net/qcu87ok9/) and as you can see, a scrollbar shows up. That's because you set the width of your nav to 100%, but you also gave it a margin. Margins, borders and scrollbars are considered outside the width. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Y32/25/) will help you dealing with that.

One way to fix this is with `width: calc(100% - 10px);` on the #wrap element, which will counter the left and right margins of 5px each, but it isn't compatible with IE8. So I suggest making the bar slightly smaller, <strike>or putting it inside an additional wrapper which is set to 100% width but doesn't have margins.</strike> Mmm, that doesn't seem to work. Perhaps there's something else...

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation even if i change margin to 0px it still not working